# Describe set of $z^2$ as $z$ moves over 2nd quadrant and show it is open and connected

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

**Problem:** Describe the set of points $z^2$ as $z$ varies over the second quadrant: $\{z = x + iy : x < 0 \text{ and } y > 0 \}$. Show this is an open connected set. (Hint: use the polar representation of $z$.)

The following is my attempt at a solution:

so $z = |z|(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta)$. Then $z^2 = |z|^2(\cos2\theta + i\sin2\theta)$. We know that for $z$ in the second quadrant, $\theta \in (\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi)$. Thus $2\theta \in (-\pi, 0)$. (I'm trying to keep $\theta$ restricted inside $(-\pi, \pi)$ as that is the convention in our class.)

Thus we can claim that the set of points $z^2$, denoted by $A = \{ |z|^2(\cos\phi + i\sin\phi) : \phi \in (-\pi, 0) \}$.

So now I'm having trouble proving it is open. I know that the idea of the proof is to claim that there is a point $a \in A$ and we choose a radius $r > 0$ and show that $B(r, a) \subset A$. And we do this by picking some point $b \in B(r, a)$, and show that $b \in A$.

I noticed that (assuming I described the set correctly), $A$ is essentially the union of third and fourth quadrant or $\{z = x + iy : y < 0 \}$, so I chose $r = \frac{|\operatorname{Im}(a)|}{2}$.

Suppose $b \in B(\frac{|\operatorname{Im}(a)|}{2}, a)$, I have to show that $b \in A$, but since $A$ is just the set of points where the imaginary part of the point negative, we really only have to prove $\operatorname{Im}(b) < 0$. This is where I run into problems. I feel like this should be an extremely easy proof and drawing it out, it is very clear, but I just can get the algebra to work out.

As for showing it is connected. I know I can claim that given $a, b \in A$, the line segment $ta + (1 - t)b$ for $t \in [0, 1]$ is also in $A$ because if $a = x + iy$ and $b = u + iv$, then $Im(ta + (1 - t)b) = ty + (1 - t)v$, which merely the interval $[\min(y, v])$, $\max(y, uv]$ for $t \in [0, 1]$. Since $y, v < 0$, the interval between them is surely less than zero as well. Thus line segment belongs in $A$ and so it is connected.

Can anyone help with showing it is open though?

Comment: We can just use the fact that the second quadrant is connected and that squaring is continuous, so it preserves this. Really though, I think the easiest approach is to use elementary facts about complex multiplication to show that the image of the 2nd quadrant is the (open) lower half plane, which is clearly open and connected.

Comment: But wouldn't how I defined the set of points $z^2$ already have shown that it's the lower half?

Comment: So you are done. The snippet "so $z = |z|(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta)$. Then $z^2 = |z|^2(\cos2\theta + i\sin2\theta)$" is all you need. Just keep in mind you are defining $z^2$ to be the image of the $z$, and you are showing it equals the right-hand side of the equation.

Comment: oh I see, thank you @basket!

Comment: To be clear about basket's first comment, openness isn't preserved by continuity. If $f: O \to \mathbb{C}$ is continuous and locally injective  at each point in the domain (and $O$ is a connected open set) then its image is connected.  See here for that result: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain.

Comment: One could alternatively use the open mapping theorem.